# Test coverage for a service's method

Tags: angular, jestjs, ts-jest

I am trying to test below code.

**sample.component.ts :**

```
import { CsSidenavService } from '@cs/ngui';

@Component({
  selector: 'sample-navbar',
  templateUrl: './sample.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sample.component.scss'],
})
export class NavbarComponent {
 toggleSideNav() {
    this.sideNavService.toggleState();
  }
```

In .spec file I am trying to do something like below-

**sample.component.spec.ts :**

```
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        CsNavigationModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
      ],
      declarations: [
        NavbarComponent,
      ],
      providers: [CsSidenavService],
    }).compileComponents();
  });
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NavbarComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    compiled = fixture.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
    sideNavService= new CsSidenavService();
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

 it('should check working of toggleSideNav function', () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(sideNavService,'toggleState')
    sideNavService.toggleState();
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(spy).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });
```

Below is the service file which I am importing to toggle the state of side navbar-

**sidenav.service.ts :**

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { CsSidenavItemComponent } from './cs-sidenav-item.component';
import * as ɵngcc0 from '@angular/core';
export declare enum CsSidenavState {
    HIDDEN = 0,
    EXPANDED = 1
}
export declare enum ScreenSize {
    SMALL = 0,
    LARGE = 1
}
export declare class CsSidenavService {
    private selectedItem$;
    private sidenavState$;
    private screenSize$;
    private items;
    registerItem(item: CsSidenavItemComponent): void;
    unregisterItem(item: CsSidenavItemComponent): void;
    selectItem(item: CsSidenavItemComponent): void;
    selectItemByName(name: string): void;
    getSelectedItem(): Observable<CsSidenavItemComponent>;
    getSidenavState(): Observable<CsSidenavState>;
    getScreenSize(): Observable<ScreenSize>;
    setScreenSize(size: ScreenSize): void;
    toggleState(): void;
    getItems(): CsSidenavItemComponent[];
    setSidenavState(state: CsSidenavState): void;
    static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<CsSidenavService, never>;
    static ɵprov: ɵngcc0.ɵɵInjectableDeclaration<CsSidenavService>;
}
```

Issue which I am facing -
Test case is getting passed successfully. But test coverage is showing the below line not covered.

> this.sideNavService.toggleState();

Can someone suggest what can be done?

Comment: Firstly there seems to be no connection between the service instance and the component you're testing. Secondly the component isn't involved in the test at all, so it should be no surprise it doesn't help with coverage - you spy on the service, call the spy directly then assert that it did get called.

Comment: That's what I am trying to understand. It would be helpful if you could help in understanding this. I am new to jest and I am bit lost on what needs to be done and how?

Comment: Angular has lots of documentation on testing, start with https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#component-with-a-dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing few things out. I am now able to get the test coverage to 100%.
Below is the code I have now in place.

```
describe('NavbarComponent', () => {
  let component: NavbarComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<NavbarComponent>;
  let compiled: HTMLElement;
  **const mockSideNavService:Partial<CsSidenavService> = {
    toggleState: jest.fn(()=>true)
  }**

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        CsNavigationModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
      ],
      declarations: [
        NavbarComponent
      ],
      **providers: [{provide:CsSidenavService, useValue:mockSideNavService }],**
    }).compileComponents();
  });
  it('should check working of toggleSideNav function', () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(mockSideNavService,'toggleState')
    component.toggleSideNav()
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I would call `component.toggleSideNav()` in the test, instead of `sideNavService.toggleState();`

Comment: As `toggleSideNav()` has `this.sideNavService.toggleState();` and toggleState() doesnot return anything. What will you recommend on how I should write the expect statement? As I have tried this also and keeping expect statement same as mentioned. But it was still not working. I am getting this error : **Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0**

Comment: You shouldn't call methods on the component directly. And no the spy won't get called, because again there's no connection between that service instance and the component under test.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Can you please help how I can establish this connection and execute this test successfully?